# TailwindCSS classes not working in nextjs app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

In my nextJS app, I have problems with using some TailwindCSS classes like top, left, or drop-shadow.

I tried updating Tailwind from 1.9.5 to 3.3.3, but no changes

I guess i'm importing it correctly :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

and here is my config even if my problems doesn't concern custom classes:

```
const { colors } = require(`tailwindcss/defaultTheme`)

module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: false,
    content: ["./components/**/*.js", "./pages/**/*.js"],
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.indigo,
        brique: "#cd391a",
        slate: "rgb(71, 71, 71)",
        blueBus: "#111635",
        deepBlue: "#340978",
        // "#1400FF",
        brightYellow: "#6BAA75",
        // "#FBE200",
        darkPurple: "#ffffff",
        // "#300729",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        display: ["Rubik"],
        titleFont: ["Concert One", "sans serif"],
      },
      container: {
        center: true,
        padding: {
          default: "1rem",
          md: "2rem",
        },
      },
      gridTemplateColumns: {
        // custom grid col for cards
        cards: "repeat(3, 10rem)",
      },
      height: {
        container: "calc(100vh - 256px)",
        canvasWrapper: "75vh",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I don't know what else to check to debug

EDIT :
For more informations, I'm using these classes like this for exemple :

```
  <h5 className="drag-indicator absolute left-1/2 top-1/2 text-center text-3xl font-bold text-purple-500 z-10 opacity-75 drop-shadow-xl">
          &larr; Click & drag to rotate &rarr;
        </h5>
```

About the folder structure, I have a styles folder with two files : one is index.css and has only the TailwindCSS imports in it and the other is global.scss with some style for a component reused from a previous app. Could it be the source of the problème?

Comment: Can I see how you're using these classes? Also, I'd like to see your folder structure too. It's possible that files referenced in the `purge.content` are not the files that you're trying to use these classes in.

Comment: I added some more info about your questions

Answer (score 0):

Try to add shadow property manually to tailwind.config.js
like this one inside extend:
boxShadow: {
dark: "8px 6px 24px 0px rgba(107,103,107,0.59)",
},
then you can see the purpose of problem you have